# Trying to get multiple objects with inline

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get a PurchaseOrder that can be added indefinitely many times. Maybe this is easier than I am thinking, but here is my problem in this imagine:

[image]

I would like it to where instead of adding another VendorProfile, it'll add another PurchaseOrder. My end goal is to be able to add 1, 2, 20, etc. PurchaseOrder from the same add screen. Not to be able to add a PurchaseOrder, and then a VendorProfile.
Here's some code: In models.py

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
   product = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   dollar_amount = models.FloatField()
   item_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   vendor = models.ForeignKey('VendorProfile')

class VendorProfile(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=512)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

In admin.py

```
class ProductInline(admin.StackedInline):
   model = VendorProfile 
   extra = 3


class PurchaseOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   #...
   inlines = [ProductInline]
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you whant associate many PurchaseOrder's to one VerndorProfile. In such a case it would be better to use ManyToManyField.
Example:

models.py:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    dollar_amount = models.FloatField()
    item_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{} {}'.format(self.product, self.dollar_amount)


class VendorProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    purchased_orders = models.ManyToManyField('PurchaseOrder')
```

admin.py

```
class VendorProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('purchased_orders', )
admin.site.register(VendorProfile, VendorProfileAdmin)
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly I edited the images to hopefully make more sense. http://i.imgur.com/oXurRe3.png?1 and http://i.imgur.com/PnRWAnr.png?1 So that when I go to add PurchaseOrder, I can add one, and then I have the option of adding 2, 3, 4, etc. The problem I'm running in to is it gives me an error. Maybe I'm overthinking this and there is an easier way to just add an implementation that says "Add another Purchase Order"

Comment: I do not think there is a way to add multiple PurchaseOrder items at once on the "Add PurchaseOrder" page. I've updated the picture. Maybe it will be clearer.